# get Dateobject out of timestamp in milliseconds

Tags: php, timestamp

I have a timestamp in milliseconds, e.g. 1358328037000

what is the fastest way to get the Dateobject out of it? I need it in this way Date(2013,0,2,12,2,20)

Answer (score 0):

```
$mil = 1358328037000;
$seconds = $mil / 1000;
echo date("y,m,d,h,i,s", $seconds);
```

I have not tried this myself but it should help you to reach your goal.

I also recommend you to check out these pages

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DateTime](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class, which has been available since PHP 5.3. The function you are looking for here is [createFromFormat](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$dt = \DateTime::createFromFormat('U', (string) floor(1358328037000/1000));
echo $dt->format('Y,m,d,h,i,s');
```

This will drop the microseconds, which isn't a big deal if they aren't important.